# What algorithm is used in this animation from Tatami Galaxy?

Tags: algorithm, animation

Is there a name for this type of effect where many area sizes are increased/decreased in relation to each other? I'm looking for some type of algorithm, formula, logic, etc. for recreating this. Here is the effect (which I believe was created in After Effects):

[image: The Tatami Galaxy (Yojouhan Shinwa Taikei / 四畳半神話大系) - Clear END]

Source: [The Tatami Galaxy (Yojouhan Shinwa Taikei / 四畳半神話大系) - Clear END](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ewICfFjc4CI)

Comment: I think perhaps it might be "constraint-based" or "rule-based" modelling. 

Ivan Sutherland's sketchpad program (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sketchpad) perhaps may have been the first.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like a [voronoi diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram) with a non-Euclidean distance metric. Probably not [Manhattan L1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry) but something close related, but maybe [Mahalanobis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahalanobis_distance) with some kind of restriction on seed point generation and movement.

A similar result may be calculated with [Weight-proportional Space Partitioning Using Adaptive Voronoi Diagrams](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10707-006-0006-8) when reducing spatial resolution of the domain.

I guess yo'll find similar examples in [ShaderToy](https://www.shadertoy.com/) if you look for voronoi examples, which code you could study, and could be much simpler than the algorithm in the paper.

Comment: This looks very close to what I was looking for thank you! Question though, is there a related formula on how to achieve the rectangular effect for each node? From what I've looked into it seems like all examples have voronoi diagrams with polygons. The weight-proportional paper had a rectangular image on google but this paper is paywalled.